# Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader_Autoloader

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I am using Zend Debugger to debug my php application built based on the Zend Framework.
Currently I am running the 1.10.6 version. 
When debugging my application i Get this error:

```
Compile Error: /var/www/Zend/ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php line 36 - Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader_Autoloader
```

Is this just a bug in the Zend Framework or does it have anything to do with a misconfiguration in my application.php?

```
$paths = array(

    realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../library'),
    '.',
);
*/


defined('APPLICATION_PATH') 
    or define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../application'));
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    or define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library'),
)));    


//require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');   
require_once('Zend/Application.php');

$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/events.ini'  
);

$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

Comment: Probably the error is with the configuration of Zend Debugger. I already have this error when testing Zend Debugger. The bad thing is that I've not solved this... When testing, my application had no errors.

Comment: well it terminates my debug session when i jump over it. So I HAVE to solve this issue first

Comment: What I'm suggesting you is to look at the debugger, not the code, this errors occurs not only with the autoloader. For example, take a look at this: 
http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Using-Zend-Studio-5-5-0-Debugger-td644517.html
http://markmail.org/message/xyyntiwkfja2awya

I've nerver seen the solution for this issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're include()-ing or require()-ing the file somewhere without knowing it. Try sticking this code at the top of Autoloader.php:

```
if (!isset($GLOBALS['zend_autoloader_loaded'])) {
    $GLOBALS['zend_autoloader_loaded'] = true;
}
else {
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
    die;
}
```

The trace will indicate where Autoloader.php is being required for the 2nd time.

Answer (score 3):

turn off zend optimizer if you are using zend server

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your using Zend Server - which I think includes this by default.